# Running a shell script on several files as inputs

Tags: bash, shell

I have a shell command with the following format:

```
my_cmd -I file1.inp -O file1.out
```

Where some processing is done on `file1.inp` and the results are stored in `file1.out`

In my main directory, I have many files with the format: `*.inp` and I would like to run this command for all of them and the store the results to `*.out`. Can I only use shell script to achieve this?

Comment: sounded like an average question, but generated a lot of good answers, so I guess the question was good after all :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a simple loop:

```
for file in *.inp ; do
    my_cmd -I "${file}" -O "${file%%.inp}.out"
done
```

`${file%%.inp}` is a so called [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html). It will effectively remove the extension `.inp` from the input filename.

---

One thing (thanks Jean-François Fabre). If the folder does not contain any `.inp` files the above loop would run once with `$file` having the literal value `*.inp`. To avoid that you need to set the `nullglob` option:

```
shopt -s nullglob # set the nullglob option
for file in *.inp ; do
    my_cmd -I "${file}" -O "${file%%.inp}.out"
done
shopt -u nullglob # unset the nullglob option
```

Comment: I would add a test to see if `$file` is a file. 1) it could be a directory, 2) if there are no `.inp` files in the directory it calls the command with `*.inp`

Comment: An answer should focus on the problem asked by the OP. What you suggested might(!) be worth to implement for the OP but it is off-topic in my answer.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre You are right about the second point. Good catch!

Comment: Note that this last behavior can also be avoided by setting the shell option `nullglob` : after `shopt -s nullglob`, the `*.inp` will resolve to the empty string, avoiding the loop body from being executed.

Comment: I've added an example using the `nullglob` options. Thanks for the hint

Comment: @hek2mgl thanks it works! BTW, do you know how to run the same thing in parallel using gnu parallel?

Comment: @motam79 you can fork your instructions by using the `&` symbol. In your for loop, you could write `my_cmd -I "${file}" -O "${file%%.inp}.out" &`

Answer (score 4):

Using GNU `parallel`

```
parallel my_cmd -I {} -O {.}.out ::: *.inp
```

By default, this will jobs in parallel, one job per core. `{}` is an unchanged argument, `{.}` is the same argument minus its extension. The arguments are taken from the words that follow `:::`.

Answer (score -3):

```
ls *.inp| xargs -l1 -I % my_cmd -I % -O %.out
```

Comment: @Aaron No, it can't. That's (for example) because `ls` will modify filenames as soon as they contain problematic letters. `find` won't do that. Don't parse the results of `ls`. Period.

Comment: I agree but I'm confused now. Please check your comment. Is it a typo?

Comment: Well I still understand myself, but I'm not a native english speaker so I may very well have written gibberish. I can't edit the comment anymore so I've deleted it and wrote another one

Comment: You can generally replace an unsafe `ls | xargs` by a safer `find -exec`

Comment: Ok. Agreed! BTW, I'm also not a native Enlish speaker, so probably I got it wrong..

Comment: While these commands may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how they answer the question. Please [include an explanation for your commands](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post. **Flaggers / reviewers:** [For command-only answers such as this one, downvote, don't delete!](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260413/2747593) ([The same goes for incorrect answers.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/287563/2747593))